# How to avoid list refreshing after calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have list in my fragment and NavigationDrawer in MainActivity. From NavigationDrawer I'm calling that fragment. When I scroll a little bit and open NavigationDrawer again, list refreshes and starts from the top. (it should still be in the same position even if Navigation Drawer is open) I think that the main reason for this is because onDrawerOpened I have `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` which restarts everything. (when I comment that line everything is okay, but ActionBar icons are still there). I have to call it because onDrawerOpen I need to hide icons from the ActionBar.

That's how I set my ActionBarToggle (I call this method in onCreate method before `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`):

```
private void setActionBarDrawerToggle(){
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            View view = getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };
}
```

This is onPrepareOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        switch (location) {
            case "eat":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "contest":
            case "other":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "public":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "one_day":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "taxi":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "cinema":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case "events":
            case "souvenirs":
            case "cash_machines":
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.today).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.directions_bus).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
            default:
                menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);                    
                menu.findItem(R.id.sort_by).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
                //menu.findItem(R.id.working_cafes).setVisible(false);
                break;
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Any ideas how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried hiding the ActionBar instead of invalidating it?
Something like this:

ActionBar bar =  getSupportActionBar();
bar.hide();

and just calling .show(); when you want to show it again?

Comment: Well, I need to have ActionBar, I just don't want to have ActionBar icon's